# MS Access freezing when running a loop of queries

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have thousands of insert queries to run inside of a loop. MS Access 2010 seems to freeze up. At the beginning it was showing the run query progress bar working fine for each insert query so I do not think this is a locking issue. I am going to let it continue for the next hour or so just to see if it really is still working behind the scenes.

In the meantime, is there any kind of statement I should be using to avoid these freezes? Like DoEvents or something?

Comment: Yikes.  There has to be a better way.  In the meantime, how do you execute these queries?  `DoCmd.RunSQL`, or what?

Comment: Yes, by DoCmd.RunSQL. Right now I have a button on a form that when pressed it goes through a table of 1700 records. These 1700 records have a number field that tell me how many rows to insert into a separate table (linked by a foreign key). However some of these 1700 records have a number of 700 so that is 700 inserts for just one of the original 1700 records

Comment: I've been in the "seems to be frozen" situation many times ... and many hours, heh heh. Sometimes it proves to be avoidable, but that is usually achieved by a re-design. Which I would wish for any application running 'thousands of insert queries'.

Comment: I think the simple answer is No, there isn't some kind of statement such as you were looking for.  `DoEvents` -- sure, try it and see.  Getting a stronger processor (or processors) might be the ticket.

Comment: You might put a debug.print X of Y statement in your loop, and run the routine from the IDE so that you see those statements going by to make sure something is really happening.

Comment: @Smandoli, thanks, This will only be a one time set up in order to initially set up the database and migrate some data over. But it is good to know that the queries might still be running even though it seems to be frozen.

Comment: @Knox, that is a good idea, I will try that next. I'd assume the vba IDE would lock up at the same time as the database view of ms access, but hopefully I am assuming wrong

Comment: That's where `DoEvents` could be a distinct help. And of course, there is the good ol' Task Manager CPU graph. :-D  Ultimately if these processes run hours upon hours, a table to log completed events becomes useful.

Comment: Since you're using `DoCmd.RunSQL`, that likely means you did `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`.  That could be hiding an error which prevents the overall process from completing.

Comment: Good observation from HansUp.  I believe that is the hazard that prompted me to set up a log of complete (or NOT completed) events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.  As found in the comments, aside from solving some external bottleneck (CPU, bandwidth), or taking a good look at the queries to hopefully improve efficiency, all you can do is set up ways to monitor the progress so you can feel assured something is happening.  And feel happy this is a one-time migration.